# On delete set child row's parent_id to parent_id

Tags: mysql

I have a table where reach row is linked to itself using a parent_id field.

PERSON TABLE:
id
name
age
parent_id

When I delete a row, I wish for the child row to relink to the parent row of the row that is being deleted.

Can this be done using a constraint? Or must I manually code this into my program logic each time I do a delete?

Comment: I don't understand. So if I'm deleted, my son's parent becomes my dad?!?!

Comment: It's basically just a linked list, person 1 > person 2 > person 3. Delete person 2, the linked list is now 1 > 3. So in your analogy, if I'm deleted, my son will take my place to be my father's son.

Comment: The nested set model has to deal with this all the time, so there are well-worn procedures for this in that model. Perhaps that's more appropriate here?

Comment: Yes that's seem to be more appropriate for my case, thank you :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You cannot implement what you're looking for using inbuilt implementation of **CONSTRAINTS**.

The `ON DELETE *reference_option*` clause accepts 4 different values for reference option -

```
RESTRICT | CASCADE | SET NULL | NO ACTION
```

**RESTRICT** will not let you delete the record

**CASCADE** will delete the record from parent table as well as those from child tables (reference records).

**SET NULL** will let you delete the parent record and set the column value in child tables as NULL.

**NO ACTION** is equivalent to RESTRICT.

You will have to write custom code to get what you want.

Comment: So if that is the case, then does this mean I should not have a foreign key at all even though i am referencing a unique id that may or may not exist? Or have foreign key but omit the constraint?

Comment: IMO you should have FK constraint to ensure data integrity (rule out all those cases where you have a `parent_Id` which does not exist as `id`)

Comment: Ok, so have a FK constraint, but set to NO ACTION on delete. In my code logic, on delete lookup all rows that are children of the row to be deleted to reassign their parent_id, then perform the deletion. Obviously if the code logic fails, the query will return an error.